# Inno Setup - Folder to install the software, start menu folder, desktop icon all in the same page

Tags: inno-setup

How to add them to a single page?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For the "Start menu folder" part, the easiest solution is to simply move all the controls from the `SelectProgramGroupPage` to the `SelectDirPage`. And of course, shift them all down, below the existing controls.

   You should also shift the original `DiskSpaceLabel` up, next to other related controls.

   The last step is to update a tab order.

   To hide the real "Select Start Menu Folder" page, use the [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage). Had you used the [`DisableProgramGroupPage=yes`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disableprogramgrouppage), the selected folder won't show on the "Ready to Install" page.
2. For the "desktop icon", you cannot move the `TasksList` control, as that is populated only, when the "Select Additional Tasks" page is entered. You have to create your new checkbox. And use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) to bind the custom checkbox to the [`Icons` section entry](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection).

   To add an information about the "desktop icon" task on the "Ready to Install" page, you have to implement the [`UpdateReadyMemo` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=UpdateReadyMemo)

```pascal
[Setup]
DisableProgramGroupPage=no
AllowNoIcons=yes

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
    Check: ShouldCreateDesktopIcon

[Code]
var
  DesktopCheck: TNewCheckBox;

function ShouldCreateDesktopIcon: Boolean;
begin
  Result := DesktopCheck.Checked;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Offset: Integer;
begin
  { shift the original `DiskSpaceLabel` up, next to the other related controls }
  WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Top := WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + WizardForm.DirEdit.Height + ScaleY(16);

  { Move all the controls from the `SelectProgramGroupPage` to the `SelectDirPage`. }
  { And shift them all down, below the existing controls. }
  { Update tab order. }
  Offset := WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Top + WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Height + ScaleY(16) - WizardForm.SelectGroupBitmapImage.Top;
  WizardForm.SelectGroupBitmapImage.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  WizardForm.SelectGroupBitmapImage.Top := WizardForm.SelectGroupBitmapImage.Top + Offset;
  WizardForm.SelectStartMenuFolderLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  WizardForm.SelectStartMenuFolderLabel.Top := WizardForm.SelectStartMenuFolderLabel.Top + Offset;
  WizardForm.SelectStartMenuFolderBrowseLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  WizardForm.SelectStartMenuFolderBrowseLabel.Top := WizardForm.SelectStartMenuFolderBrowseLabel.Top + Offset;
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.Top := WizardForm.GroupEdit.Top + Offset;
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.TabOrder := WizardForm.GroupEdit.TabOrder + 100;
  WizardForm.GroupBrowseButton.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  WizardForm.GroupBrowseButton.Top := WizardForm.GroupBrowseButton.Top + Offset;
  WizardForm.GroupBrowseButton.TabOrder := WizardForm.GroupBrowseButton.TabOrder + 100;
  WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Top := WizardForm.GroupEdit.Top + WizardForm.GroupEdit.Height + ScaleY(16);
  WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.TabOrder := WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.TabOrder + 100;

  { create new "Create a desktop icon" checkbox }
  DesktopCheck := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  DesktopCheck.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  DesktopCheck.Top := WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Top + WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Height + ScaleY(6);
  DesktopCheck.Width := WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Width;
  DesktopCheck.Height := WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Height;
  DesktopCheck.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}');
  DesktopCheck.TabOrder := 200;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { To hide the real "Select Start Menu Folder" page }
  Result := (PageID = wpSelectProgramGroup);
end;

function UpdateReadyMemo(
  Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo,
  MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var
  S: string;
begin
  if Length(MemoUserInfoInfo) > 0 then
    Result := Result + MemoUserInfoInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  if Length(MemoDirInfo) > 0 then
    Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  if Length(MemoTypeInfo) > 0 then
    Result := Result + MemoTypeInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  if Length(MemoComponentsInfo) > 0 then
    Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  if Length(MemoGroupInfo) > 0 then
    Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  if DesktopCheck.Checked then
  begin
    S := DesktopCheck.Caption;
    StringChange(S, '&', ''); 
    Result :=
      Result + SetupMessage(msgReadyMemoTasks) + NewLine +
      Space + S + NewLine + NewLine;
  end;  
end;
```

[image: All on one page]

[image: Ready to install]

Of course, I had to [make the wizard form higher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11778292/850848), to fit all the controls.